# What is the equivalent of "teasing me"?

Tags: past-participle, phrase-request

I am trying to say that I like when I am teased. The sentence I came up with doesn't seem to be understood from a native speaker of Italian, so I am wondering what I could say to express that thought.

> Mi piace quando vengo scherzato.

I thought I could say *preso in giro*, but I would get it means also to be said something that is not true to make me believe it is true, such as when somebody says "I truly love you" or "I fell in love with you" when it is not true at all.

Is that sentence correct? Should I instead say *sono scherzato*?

I am asking for a phrase to use when somebody exaggerates something I do, or says something I don't do, just to make me smile or laugh.

Comment: kiam, se proprio non vuoi dire 'preso in giro', suggerirei 'mi piace quando vengo sollazzato', ma sembra piuttosto old-fashioned, though.

Comment: Quite simply, “scherzare” is not transitive (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scherzare/) so you cannot ”scherzare qualcuno”, whatever you mean by it.

Comment: ...while “sollazzare”, apart from being old-fashioned, is something different, more akin to “amuse, entertain”.

Comment: 'quand'ero piccolo tutti mi scherzavano'. elio e le storie tese docet.

Comment: it is also referred to the sexual sphere. saying to a woman "you tease me", means that she's somehow seducing you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy solution:

> Mi piacciono gli scherzi.

If you really need to stress the masochistic aspect of the pleasure:

> Mi piace quando mi fanno degli scherzi.
>
> Mi piace subire degli scherzi.

Several other solutions, like those listed in the answer and comments before this, are acceptable. The following ones mean "I like being made fun of", not necessarily by pretending. It may just be a humorous comment on a personal feature.

> Mi piace quando mi prendono in giro
>
> Mi piace essere preso in giro.

Instead of *preso in giro* you can be *preso per i fondelli*, *per il naso*, *per il sedere* (and grosser synonyms)...

If the teasing is more based on childish practical jokes, you can also use these:

> Mi piacciono i dispetti.
>
> Mi piace quando mi fanno i dispetti.

Comment: I don't get the "stress the masochistic aspect" part. _Fare degli scherzi_ could refer to somebody who calls me pretending to be somebody else, and making me say/do something; in that case, it would not be anything masochistic.

Comment: I just meant that _Mi piacciono gli scherzi_ does not explicitly say that you like being teased, it includes both teasing and being teased, but if you want to underline that you like when other people tease you you can use the following sentences although they are a little bit awkward.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use *mi scherzano*, but you can use one of these:

> Mi piace quando mi pigliano per il naso
>
> Mi piace quando mi sfottono
>
> Mi piace quando mi pigliano per i fondelli

They are not, in my opinion, 1:1 translations. Possibly closer to your intended meaning is:

> Mi piace quando scherzano con me

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are confessing masochistic preferences, I would say

> Mi piacciono le provocazioni intelligenti

or

> Mi piace esser provocato/a in maniera intelligente

This means that you like when someone is teasing you in a *positive* way, i.e. when someone is being playful with you and you accept to play their game because you find it challenging or sexy or for whatever other **non-masochistic** reason.

You can also say («when somebody exaggerates something I do, or says something I don't do, just to make me smile or laugh»):

> Mi piacciono le battute ironiche

or

> Mi piace l'ironia

Comment: Would you use _provocazioni_ when somebody tells me "you are always dressed like Harlequin"?

Comment: … chances are that it is an insult … depending on the context (that you only know) do you think it may be something different? Otherwise I don't think you really enjoy being teased like that unless you are being masochistic.

Comment: If somebody doesn't like how I match the colors of my clothes, they could say that phrase. Clearly, accepting it as non offensive depends from the person who said it and from the tone, but I don't classify accepting it at the same level of "slap my face hard because I like to feel pain."

Comment: Maybe what you really like is "healthy criticism", in this case you could say «*mi piacciono le critiche*».