# Può "dispetto" essere sinonimo di "scherzo"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, nouns

Leggendo questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1601/707), sono stata stupita da queste frasi

> Mi piacciono i *dispetti*
>
> Mi piace quando mi fanno i *dispetti*

che vengono proposte come possibili traduzioni dell'inglese

> I like when I am teased.

Se ho capito bene la spiegazione del post, in questo contesto i "dispetti" sarebbero certi scherzi piuttosto infantili. È così?

Ho cercato la definizione di ["dispetto"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dispetto2/)  nel vocabolario Treccani e ho trovato questa accezione:

> **2.** Atto compiuto espressamente e con malignità per far dispiacere altrui, per irritare o procurare danno: *fare un d., dei d.; ricevere un d.; l’ha detto solo per fare un d. a me*. Anche, il sentimento, l’intenzione per cui l’atto si compie: *l’ha fatto per d.* (talora, lo stesso che *per ripicca*); *pare che faccia per d. a non capire*. Riferito a fatti, eventi, circostanze, la locuz. *per d.* è spesso adoperata come inciso: *io lo so, ma, per d., non te lo dico*; e con sign. attenuato: *finalmente il salto gli riuscì, ma proprio in quel momento, per d., non c’era nessuno a guardarlo; quante volte, tornandoci sopra,... gli venivano in mente, quasi per d., parole che tutte sarebbero state meglio di quell’insulso ‘si figuri!’* (Manzoni).

Leggendo tutto questo, a me non sembra che si tratti proprio di scherzi, ma invece di cose abbastanza serie. Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "dispetti" nelle frasi precedenti?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nel contesto del comportamento infantile (e anche di rapporti amichevoli tra adulti), il dispetto è un atto volto a infastidire ma senza intenzioni malevole: è piuttosto, come ha intuíto, qualcosa che si fa per amor di scherzo. Si veda la definizione del [*Sabatini-Coletti*](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/D/dispetto.shtml):

> Azione che ha il solo fine di infastidire qlcu., dettata da malignità,
>   o, al contrario, **da un'intenzione scherzosa**

C’è però una differenza semantica rispetto a *scherzo*: se chi scherza si prende gioco di qualcuno, chi fa a un’altra persona un dispetto le dà noia in maniera scherzosa, ma non cerca di beffarla, facendole credere ciò che non è.

La parola *dispetto*, nella sua connotazione scherzosa, si applica molto piú spesso ai bambini che agli adulti.

A conferma dell’affinità semantica — ma, si badi, non dell’equivalenza — tra *scherzo* e *dispetto*, ecco una possibile traduzione italiana della celebre domanda posta dai bambini alla vigilia di Ognissanti (*Halloween*), «treat or tricks?», cosí come la riporta il quotidiano *[Corriere della Sera](http://archiviostorico.corriere.it/2000/ottobre/31/cardinale_sconfessa_Halloween_co_0_0010312082.shtml)* in un suo articolo del 31 ottobre 2000:

> Treats or **tricks**, dolcetti o **dispetti**? Secondo il cardinale Carlo
>   Maria Martini, più che altro si tratta di dispetti, un brutto **scherzo**
>   che stiamo giocando alla nostra cultura […].

Nell’uso prevale «dolcetto o scherzetto?», ma quest’alternativa (decisamente minoritaria) rende bene l’idea della natura bambinesca degli scherzetti e del loro scopo di dar noia, per scherzo.

Comment: Tutto giusto, tranne che il fatto che per *trick or treat* mi è capitato solo di sentire “dolcetto o scherzetto”, e quindi quanto meno non possiamo considerare l'altra versione come *la* traduzione italiana. Per il poco che vale, Ngram Viewer non conosce le due locuzioni, ma una normale ricerca con Google dà più di 200.000 risultati con “dolcetto o scherzetto” e 121 con “dolcetto o dispetto”.

Comment: @DaG È vero. Correggo _la_ con _una_. Grazie.